# SASS Element same styles but some different

Tags: css, sass

Hello i was just wondering how i would achieve doing two elements with the same styles but also  some styles different example below of how i would like it to be compiled to.

```
 .bubble-right,
.bubble-left {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 225px;
    height: 224px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url('../images/Speech-bubble-FDEB1.png');
}

.bubble-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 25px 25px;
}

.bubble-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a common `bubble` class, then make a `bubble-left` and `bubble-right` which contains the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like gunr2171 said, you would make something along the lines of the code below.  Both elements would share the bubble class and each individual element would either have bubble-left or bubble-right as another class.  I have created the example in scss format below:

```
.bubble{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 225px;
    height: 224px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url('../images/Speech-bubble-FDEB1.png');
    &.bubble-left{
        float: left;
        margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
    }

    &.bubble-right {
        float: right;
        margin: 0 0 25px 25px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats the way to do it. If you want to tidy it up even more you can change the `&.bubble-left` to `&-left`, and the same for the right.

Answer (score 1):

Very pragmatic:

```
.bubble {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 50px 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 225px;
    height: 224px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image: url('../images/Speech-bubble-FDEB1.png');
}

.bubble-right {
    @extend .bubble;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.bubble-left {
    @extend .bubble;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```